# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority err

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-go-sdk

I am attempting to create simple vcn but i am getting this error:

```
Post https://iaas.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/20160918/vcns: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
details of vcn creation: { RawResponse=<nil> Vcn={ CidrBlock=<nil> CompartmentId=<nil> Id=<nil> LifecycleState= DefaultDhcpOptionsId=<nil> DefaultRouteTableId=<nil> DefaultSecurityListId=<nil> DefinedTags=map[] DisplayName=<nil> DnsLabel=<nil> FreeformTags=map[] TimeCreated=<nil> VcnDomainName=<nil> } Etag=<nil> OpcRequestId=<nil> }
```

I was able to create a vcn in the past but not with the recent version i am getting this error. My current $HOME/.oci/config should be okay because i am able to use the oci cli and terraform with it. Here is the code that i am attempting to execute.

```
package main

import (
  "context"
  "fmt"

  "github.com/oracle/oci-go-sdk/common"
  "github.com/oracle/oci-go-sdk/core"
  "github.com/oracle/oci-go-sdk/identity"
)

func main() {
  configProvider := common.DefaultConfigProvider()

  response, err := createNetworkVCN(configProvider)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("details of vcn creation: %v", response)

  return
}

func createNetworkVCN(configProvier common.ConfigurationProvider) (response core.CreateVcnResponse, err error) {
  client, err := core.NewVirtualNetworkClientWithConfigurationProvider(configProvier)
  if err != nil {
    return response, err
  }
  ctx := context.Background()
  request := core.CreateVcnRequest{}
  request.CidrBlock = common.String("10.0.0.0/16")
  request.CompartmentId = common.String("<redacted for security reasons>")
  request.DisplayName = common.String("TestVCN")
  request.DnsLabel = common.String("testDNS")

  response, err = client.CreateVcn(ctx, request)
  if err != nil {
    return response, err
  }

  return response, err
}
```

note that I am using dep to maintain version 2.1.0 of the oci-go-sdk package

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem solved itself. I retried the exact same code and now its working.